Proof of inequality concerning Newton's binomial formula
In a book I'm reading, some inequalities regarding Newton's binomial are introduced.
One is presented like this:
Given Newton's binomial formula
$$(a+b)^n=\binom{n}{0}a^n+\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2+...+\binom{n}{n-1}ab^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}b^n$$
and taking into account that, setting a=b=1 results in the following
$$2^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}$$
Assuming $a > 0$ and $0 < \epsilon < a$,
from Newton's binomial formula it follows that
$$(a+\epsilon)^n=a^n+\epsilon\left[ \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}\epsilon +...+ \binom{n}{n}\epsilon^{n-1} \right]< a^n+\epsilon a^{n-1}\left(2^n-1\right)$$
I can't understand how this inequality can be proven

$\epsilon < a \implies a^{n - k} \epsilon^{k - 1} < a^{n - k} \cdot a^{k - 1} = a^{n - 1}$. Also $\binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n - \binom{n}{1}$ and $\binom{n}{1} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thanks, this helped me put my thoughts in order: $a^{n - k} \epsilon^{k - 1} < a^{n - k} \cdot a^{k - 1} = a^{n - 1}$ (maybe you meant $\binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n - \binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{0} = 1$, is that right?)

Yes you are correct. Sorry for the typo.

$$\begin{align*}\varepsilon a^{n-1}(2^n-1) &= \varepsilon a^{n-1} \bigg(\color{red}{\binom{n}{1}}+\binom{n}{2}+...\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}\bigg)\\
&=\varepsilon \underbrace{\bigg(\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-1}+...\binom{n}{n-1}a^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}a^{n-1}\bigg)}_{g(n;a)}
\end{align*} 
$$
since $0 <\varepsilon< a \implies  a \cdot \varepsilon < a\cdot a$. Then we have
$$g(n;a) = \bigg(\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}\cdot a+...+\binom{n}{n}a^{n-1}\bigg)$$
conclusion follows from what we said above.

So the key is $0 <\varepsilon< a \implies  a \cdot \varepsilon < a\cdot a$ therefore for example $a^{n-2}\cdot a > a^{n-2}\cdot \epsilon$ ?

Exactly, and also give a look at the red part but I think you’ve already figured out!

Not really! I know that $\binom{n}{1}=n$ but I don't see what makes it so special in this case. Now I am in trouble again.

@Gianmatteo I’m highlighting the fact that the term $\binom{n}{0}= 1$ is missing since is subtracted

Ah, yes, I actually figured that out form $2^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}$ which is $2^n-1=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+...\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}$. Thank you!
